# Using Command line to add files to xcode project

Tags: xcode, bash, command-line

I am trying to write a bash script that downloads a bunch of classes from the internet, inserts them into an existing (or maybe not?) xcode project and compiles them using xcodebuild into a static library.

However, I could not find a way to add classes to the project via command line, but only by gui.

Is there any way to do so?

In addition, is there any way to create an xcode project via the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/).

Regarding your second question about creating a project via the command line, check this link: [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/)

If I remember correctly the terminal command should be something like `cmake -G Xcode .....`

Comment: Thanks for the cmake :) I've read about cocoapods, however, this script needs to be portable, and thus cannot depend on installing any software on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

An old problem and I haven't found a valid solution, but actually, with a bit knowledge from the community, it wasn't that hard to solve. I published my results in the github project [XCodeControl](https://github.com/ikrabbe/XCodeControl).

You need a basic xcode project created by **xcode** though. It should be possible to create an empty xcode project pattern and copy+modify that to create a new project.